# VBA Connect to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I am trying to setup a remote database connection to a server running MySQL version 5.0.96.  When I execute I get the following error.

Any assistance is appreciated.

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

Here is my connection code:
Public Function opendb()

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim User_Name As String
Dim Password As String
Dim Database_Name As String

Server_Name = Sheets("_config").Range("B2").value
User_Name = Sheets("_config").Range("B3").value
Password = Sheets("_config").Range("B4").value
Database_Name = Sheets("_config").Range("B5").value

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.0.96 Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=Server_Name;" & _
    "DATABASE=Database_Name;" & _
    "USER=User_Name;" & _
    "PASSWORD=Password;" & _
    "Option=3"
```

End Function

Comment: you definitely have the driver installed and registered?

Comment: I downloaded and installed Connector/ODBC 5.2.6 from MySQL site.  I added a few references to the project.  I was considering this is the problem but wasn't sure.  Do I need to add a specific reference or is it something else?

Comment: downloaded...and installed? Can you connect if you make an ODBC DSN through the windows utility? (`C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` depending on if it's a 64 bit driver or not)

Comment: Yes I am able to connect with the windows utility.
Im running windows 7 64 bit but I need to use the system32\odbcad32.exe for testing.

Comment: possibly a typo but was there no semi colon after your server name in your original connection string?

Comment: That was a typo.  It has been adjusted but still not getting my connected.

Comment: Maybe I'm way off - but I'm confused, at least i've never seen this done that way - but your servername, databasename..they're not concatenated? You're trying to connect to a server named Server_name, a database called database_name ...  I don't think there's a way to do in-string references in VBA

Comment: I have also inserted the credentials directly into the code but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL server is running 5.0.96.  DO NOT INSTALL MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.2.6.  This driver is NOT backwards compatible from VBA.  If you have it installed and you are having the same problem I did do the follow:

1) FIRST remove any User & System Data Sources you have added

2) Uninstall all ODBC 5.2 drivers

3) Installed Connector/ODBC 3.51.30.  (You May Need to Reboot)

4) Make your Connection String > DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};

Hope this saves you lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim User_Name As String
Dim Password As String
Dim Database_Name As String

Server_Name = Sheets("_config").Range("B2").value
User_Name = Sheets("_config").Range("B3").value
Password = Sheets("_config").Range("B4").value
Database_Name = Sheets("_config").Range("B5").value

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.0.96 Driver};" & _
"SERVER=" & Server_Name & ";" & _
"DATABASE=" & Database_Name & ";" & _
"USER=" & User_Name & ";" & _
"PASSWORD=" & Password & ";" & _
"Option=3"
```

There might be other problems with your drivers but when I tested the code you posted on my end I got the same error - it's not going to read your variables unless you concat them

Edit - I'm using a 5.2a server - when I try to connect using 5.0.96 I get the same error again , but of course using the 5.2a driver in the connection string works fine.  So you will probably need to download the 5.0.96 driver specifically. I did a little searching and couldnt find it, I'll keep looking around for a minute

Comment: I would think 5.2 is backwards compatible with 5.0.96.  But to rule that out I will search for that driver.

Answer (score -1):

You may write **Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'NEW STATEMENT**
instead of **Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection**

Comment: What difference would that make?